# Combine these two methods

Tags: java

I would like to try and combine the two methods below into one:

```
public void add(String property, Parameter p) {
    if (errorMap.containsKey(property)) {
        ArrayList<Parameter> existingFiles = errorMap.get(property);
        if (!existingFiles.contains(p)) {
          errorMap.get(property).add(p);    
        }            
    } else {
        ArrayList<Parameter> listOfActFiles = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
        listOfActFiles.add(p);
        errorMap.put(property, listOfActFiles);
    }

}

public void addSimpleErrorMessage(String message) {
    if(message != null) {
        errorMessage.add(message);
    }
}
```

The first method contructs a map where the keys are `String` and the values are an `ArrayList`.

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Parameter>> errorMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Parameter>>();
```

I want to try and add in a second piece of information which is the simple error message (method 2). HashMap is not complex enough to hold that information, but I like the way it will only take unique values, and it is eash to iterate over, and pass around.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could there be more than one error message per map key? Are those error messages linked to the `Parameter` objects?

Comment: No, there should only be one error per map key. The ArrayList is basically a list of files, where this particular error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you create a new class to store in your map as the value object. This class should contain your original `ArrayList<Parameter>`, plus include the string error message.

You can then get the object from the map and populate the error message (through a setter method).